# Scheduling task in Javascript to run 1 hour after a specific action for each user

Tags: javascript, scheduled-tasks

I am creating an application in Javascript. The app should run a function one hour after a user has done a specifc action. What can I use to create these scheduled tasks to run the function?

Explanation of the use case: A user clicks her status to "active", after one hour the status should automatically be changed to "inactive".

Comment: But the page will reload several times during this one hour, don't you think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) for that:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    // Task
}, 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

And [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) to stop timeout in extra cases:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if this is too resource-heavy? This has to be run on the server.

Comment: @Riku No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

When the status is set to active send a message to the server and record the time. Then have a recurring function like the one below that runs every so often to check that the time has not expired.

```
function checkStatus( ) {

    function check( ) {
        //Check with server. Should I set status to inactive

        var timer = setTimeout(check, 60 * 1000);
    }
    check();
}
```

If a user closes the browser and re-opens it then if the time has not expired on the server you can set status to active and keep running the function.